# Не работает svg спрайт

Tags: css, svg

Используется шаблонизатор Smarty, в index.tpl подключается файл svg.tpl. При мер из него:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
<symbol id="chevron-left" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
    <path fill="black" d="M15.41 7.41L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L10.83 12z"/>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

Затем через use подключается иконка:

```
<svg class="icon" width="18" height="18" fill="#cccccc">
    <use xlink:href="#chevron-left" />
</svg>
```

Проблема в том, что на главной странице иконки отображаются, но на всех остальных страницах они не видны, svg спрайт в коде есть, но use не работает

Comment: Сайт из сети доступен? Надо взглянуть. И какой указан doctype ?

Comment: Сейчас только на локалке. <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Я сам использую такой метод, но у меня подобных проблем не возникало. Правка я smarty не юзаю уже давно.

Comment: Думаете это может быть из-за шаблонизатора?

Comment: Можно ссылку на какой-то сайт рабочий, где используются спрайты?

Comment: Как вариант, smarty, по каким то причинам,  заменяет теги на html коды. 

http://polymetrica.ru/ (обратный звонок, подвал, блок, как мы работаем).
Я просто щас этим сайтом занимаюсь.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде все так-же, но тут одностраничник, у меня на главной тоже всё работает, а вот на других страницах нет.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть исходный код в браузере, может там что увидите - версия, что smarty изменяет теги на html коды.

Comment: Смотрел, в том-то и дело, что абсолютно все одинаково, при этом такая же проблема и у другого человека.

Comment: Если сможете, как нибудь предоставить код (например bitbucket), я попробую посмотреть.

Comment: Ссылка на гугл диск: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-v9nJuH47XiSWFrWUFsRFo5MHM/view?usp=sharing. Я там уже менял многое, для примера нужно найти <use xlink:href="#chevron-right" />

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40005/discussion-between-olegatro-and--).